# Samsung Galaxy GT-P7510 won't charge

Tags: battery, charging, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have a [Samsung Galaxy Tab](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_10_1_p7510-3894.php) GT-P7510/M32 32 GB. I can't get it to charge. I plugged charger in one time and showed the battery was empty and had a yellow triangle with exclamation point point in it. I tried a different charger and that didn't work either. It did power on and go off because of dead battery.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cable? Is there anything printed on your current cable like 28AWG?

Answer (score 0):

Basic things to check:

- Is the charger broken? (try a different charger)
- Is the charger the correct voltage and current for the phone? (check your phone specs and see if they match what's written on the charger, try a wall charger and a usb charger)
- Is the battery broken? (try a different battery if you can find someone with the same tab)